# Finalizer called too early on CGO allocated memory

Tags: go, segmentation-fault, cgo

I have a project where I need to load a big image using a C library and I want to avoid copying the data into Go managed memory. For this I am using `godata := unsafe.Slice((*uint8)(cdata), size)` to create a slice that points to unmanaged memory.

Then I call `runtime.SetFinalizer(&godata, free)` to allow the memory to be freed when the slice is GC'd.

My problem is that the finalizer is called before the last use of `godata` causing a segfault.

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char* allocate(int size) {
  return (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
}

void free_allocated(unsigned char *c) {
  free(c);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "runtime"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

type dummy struct {
    Data []uint8
}

func allocate(size int) *dummy {
    cdata := C.allocate((C.int)(size))
    godata := unsafe.Slice((*uint8)(cdata), size)
    runtime.SetFinalizer(&godata, func(data *[]uint8) {
        println("Freeing")
        C.free_allocated(cdata)
    })
    // The issue does not occur without wrapping godata in a Dummy struct
    return &dummy{Data: godata}
}

func main() {
    println("Start")

    dummy := allocate(1_000_000_000)
    dummy.Data[100_000_000] = 1

    println("Allocated")

    println("GC")
    runtime.GC()

    // Wait to let the system reclaim the memory properly
    println("Wainting 10 seconds")
    <-time.After(10 * time.Second)

    // dummy.Data is already freed at this point, causing a fault
    println("Value is: ", dummy.Data[100_000_000])
}
```

For me 'Freeing' is printed just after 'GC'.

My question is how do I use `SetFinalizer` properly, so that this issue does not happen.

Comment: The address of your finalizer is not the same as the Data field in your struct. You copied the slice header

Comment: That would make sense, but calling `SetFinalizer(&godata[0])` (or similar) always results in the error `pointer not in allocated block`

Comment: You can't set a finalizer on memory you didn't allocate either. The finalizer must be tied to something that will be collected by the Go runtime: _"The argument obj must be a pointer to an object allocated by calling new, by taking the address of a composite literal, or by taking the address of a local variable"_

Comment: You need to tie the lifetime to a suitable object you have allocated in Go. Since you are storing that data in a `*dummy` value now, set the finalizer on that value.

Comment: I don't think that would work, because dummy can be collected while Data is still in use. F.e.: `data := dummy.Data`, 'dummy' can now be gc'd but I still have access to data.

Comment: That is true, you cannot copy the `Data` field --  `Data` is a slice, it is copied on assignment. If you want to use a finalizer, then you must store the data in an object with the same lifetime, there's no other way around it. If you are copying the container around, then you cannot control that lifetime.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to use the slice (header) as the 'container'. I'll try changing Data to be a pointer to a slice.

Comment: A pointer to a slice would work, but isn't generally safe because all slice operations create a new slice header. Having a single object that maps to the lifetime would be better, or IMHO explicit allocation should require explicit de-allocation.